# Better solution for retrieving array of tags from controller for tag-it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, jquery-plugins, tag-it

Hello I'm using Symfony2 with bootstrap in my project. I would just like to ask for better solutions for this problem.

I tried to get all the tags stored from my database and assign them to the availableTags attribute of the tag-it plugin.

So I came up with this solution.

Here's my controller code:

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/ask", name="ask")
 * @Security( "has_role( 'ROLE_USER' )" )
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template
 */
public function askAction() {

    $tags = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VerySoftAskMeBundle:Tag')->findAll();


    $entity = new Question();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'tags' => $tags
    );
}
```

Here's my twig template:

```
<label class="col-lg-1 text-left askLabels" for="tagField">Tags</label>
<input id="tagField" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-11">
<input id="fieldTags" type="hidden" value="{{ tags|join(',') }}">
```

And here's my script:

```
$('#tagField').tagit({
    availableTags: $('#fieldTags').val().split(',')
});
```

Comment: Yes it works but I think it's not the best way.

Comment: Which part of the implementation you are not happy with?

Comment: the joining and the splitting part

Comment: One more question: where is your Javascript code? In template file or in a js file?

Comment: It's in the template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it directly in your javascript, instead of doing this twice:

```
$('#tagField').tagit({
    availableTags: ["{{ tags|join('", "')|raw }}"]
});
```

And remove the hidden input:

```
<input id="fieldTags" type="hidden" value="{{ tags|join(',') }}">
```

Comment: what didn't work? It would define the array of all tags (If your previous code worked)

Comment: could you share what is the out put of `availableTags: ["{{ tags|join('", "') }}"]`

Comment: it just displays all the tags seperated by a comma everytime the autocomplete suggestion is shown..

java,javascipt,php,html,css,c++.....

Comment: When you view the source of the page, you should see something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3toh1wjp5mq3hl/preview.png). if you see different, i suggest you copy the code again. I think you may have copied old code.

Comment: Nope... [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5l7eo70bz4tmi1k/output.png) is the output..

Comment: I think, if this part is the only point, its the last solution :) have you tried the updated code. The modification is very little.